# Правильно ли объедниять все CSS-файлы в один через Webpack?

Tags: css, laravel, webpack, npm

Правильно ли объедниять все CSS-файлы в один через Webpack? К примеру, у меня есть один файл, в котором описаны все стили основных элементов. Но также есть на других страницах CSS-файлы разного вода библиотек, к примеру, Lighbox или Select2, и многие другие. Если объединить все эти файлы в один, то получится большой файл, который будет замедлять загрузку страницы. То же касается стилей, которые как-то призваны изменить типичный блок на одной из страницы. Заменить цвет, увеличить шрифт. Нужно ли это все объединять в одно? Интересует, как это делают профи. Как объединять только те файлы, которые нужны на текущей странице?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас многостраничный сайт, то лучше в одном 'main.css' хранить стили компонентов которые будут встречаться на всех страницах сайта и являються неизменными, (например те что относяться к `<header>`, `<footer>`) а в отдельные css (homepage.css, page.css...) групировать те, где это необходимо на текущем подходе. Что б не перегружать невостребованым css браузер пользователя. + И желательно чистить css подключаемых библиотек от неиспользуемых свойств.

Answer (score 1):

Не проблема, это можно.
Но идеально просчитать [critical css](https://medium.com/web-standards/critical-css-39e479af038e)